# Correct use of the additionalHeaders in webbrowser.navigate on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, http-headers, browser, windows-phone

Hey I'm trying to add additional header to webbrowser.natigate on windows phone but i keep getting an error and don't know what I'm writhing wrong.

I use:

```
string additionalHeaders = "Origin: http://webpage.com"; 
webBrowser2.Navigate(new Uri(m.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),,additionalHeaders);
```

but I get an argument missing do I have to also define a Postdata as the 2 argument? 
It is on windows Phone the navigate take 3 arguments. [info snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can't leave a parameter empty. Try setting it to null:

```
webBrowser2.Navigate(new Uri(m.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), null, additionalHeaders);
```

If it doesn't work, you can try using an empty array instead:

```
webBrowser2.Navigate(new Uri(m.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), new byte[0], additionalHeaders);
```